# Headers, User-Agents, Url Requests in Ubuntu

Tags: python, html, ubuntu, url, beautifulsoup

Currently scraping LINK for products, deploying my script on a ubuntu server. This site requires you to specify User-Agent and url header related stuff. As I am using Ubuntu and connecting to a proxy server on Ubuntu, what should my "hdr" variable be within this script:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import etree
import smtplib
import urllib2, sys
url = "http://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/product/22422/adidas-superstar-80s"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(url,headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

This script works just fine on coming off my computer, however not sure what I would specify as browser or user-agent for ubuntu.

The code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import etree
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import urllib2, sys
url = "http://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/product/22422/adidas-superstar-80s"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(url,headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
result = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"availability"})
```

returns the error code: urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
But this only occurs on Ubuntu, not off local machine

Comment: One that doesn't suggest _human_ would be `'Python-urllib/2.1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to specify different `User-Agent` strings based on the operating systems where the script is running. You can leave it as is.

You can go further and start rotating `User-Agent` value - for instance, randomly picking it up from the [`fake-useragent`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-useragent)'s list of real world user agents.

Comment: please view the edit made above, I'm receiving the `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` error

Comment: @ColeWorld one possibility is that your IP might be already banned by the site.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the whole urllib2 thing, but if you are just trying to get the string within the html, you are importing way too much stuff here. For the url you've provided, the following is sufficient to scrape the text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
```

As for the `user-agent`, that depends whether you want the site maintainer to know about your existence or not, mostly it is not related to the capacity of scraping itself. For some sites you might want to hide your `user-agent` for some you might prefer it to be explicitly stated.
For the url you've provided the following code worked for me without errors:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "http://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/product/22422/adidas-superstar-80s"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

req = requests.Session()

page_raw = req.get(url, headers=hdr)

page_raw.status_code # This was 200

page_raw.encoding = "utf-8" # Just to be sure

page_text = page_raw.text

page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_text, "lxml")


page_avaliablity = page_soup.find_all("span", class_="availability")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify any agent you want. The header is just a string that is part of the protocol HTTP protocol. There is no verification that goes on in the server. Beware that the header you specify will determine how the html your request will appear i.e. older agents might not contain all the information you expect

Comment: Getting an error... `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden ` Ubuntu returns that error when running the code: `import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import etree
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import urllib2, sys
url = "http://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/product/22422/adidas-superstar-80s"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(url,headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)`